# Properties of $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ if $f(x)$ is a convex function [Zorich's book]

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that
>
> a) if a convex function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded, then it is
> constant;
>
> b) if $\lim \limits_{x\to -\infty}\dfrac{f(x)}{x}=\lim \limits_{x\to
>  +\infty}\dfrac{f(x)}{x}=0,$ for a convex function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is constant.
>
> c) for any convex function $f$ defined on an open interval
> $a<x<+\infty$ (or $-\infty<x<a$), the ratio $\dfrac{f(x)}{x}$ tends to
> a finite limit or to infinity as $x$ tends to infinity in the domain
> of definition of the function.

These problems are from Zorich's book. I have solved parts a) and b) but have some issues with part c).

I was trying to solve it by contradiction. WLOG suppose $f(x)$ is defined on $(0,\infty)$ and the $\lim \limits_{x\to +\infty}\dfrac{f(x)}{x}$
does not exist. Then $\forall \delta>0$ we can find $x_0,y_0>\delta$ such that $\left|\frac{f(x_0)}{x_0}-\frac{f(y_0)}{y_0}\right|>c$ for some $c>0$. Then I've tried to apply the definition of convexity to $\delta<x_0<y_0$ to get contradiction but failed.

Would be very grateful if you can show how to finish the proof using my approach. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know about your method, but you can show $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} = \sup_{a < x < y} \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$$

Comment: @BrianMoehring, if you can give more detailed how you obtained it and why it leads to the solution then it would be great! And I'll highly appreciate your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $f$ is convex on $(a,+\infty)$
For any number $b>a$, the convexity gives that the function $$g(x)=\frac{ f(x)-f(b)}{x-b}$$
is increasing  on $(b,+\infty)$
Thus $g$ has a limit when $x$ converges to $\infty$.
On the other hand,
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{f(b)}{x-b}=0 \quad \text{and} \quad \lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{x}{x-b}=1$$
Hence forth the conclusion.

Comment: Sorry but I guess when you are defined the function $g(x)$ the wording is not clear. You are fixing that $b$ so it should be $g_b(x)$, right? Can you clarify your sentence please!

Comment: Is this $b$ fixed or not?

Comment: @ZFR It doesn't matter. What we want is to prove that $$\lim \frac{f(x)-f(b)}{x-b}$$ exists and the eventual behavior of $g$ is not related.

Comment: And this existence is equivalent to the existence of the very first limit. "$b$ fixed or not" doesn't matter. Anyways, you can let it fixed.

Comment: When you say that $g$ has a limit when $x$ converges to $\infty$ you mean that limit is finite or $+\infinity$, right?

Comment: Yeah, without a doubt.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You really helped me!

Comment: You are welcome.